# How to delete entries and video files in a listview file browser?

Tags: java, android, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete entry and video file in a listview file browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003439/how-to-delete-entry-and-video-file-in-a-listview-file-browser)

Problem description: I wanted a "delete" function which is able to delete/remove the entry in a listview after being click then refresh itself and at the same time deleting the appropriate/residing video file in the Video_List directory? How should i do that in my current codes below?

I'm rather new in android/java can someone help me with it? Do scroll down to evaluate the problem i'm facing please... I really need the help here...